# How to parse JSON data in PHP (double quote and slash headache)

Tags: php, json, parsing

From Java I am sending this to PHP using POST web service

```
{"Laptop":{"product_brand":"dd","product_desc":"xx","product_graphics":"nVidia 2GB"}}
```

In PHP I get..

```
print_r($_POST['laptop']);
```

My JSON is..

```
{\"Laptop\":{\"product_brand\":\"dd\",\"product_desc\":\"xx\",\"product_graphics\":\"nVidia 2GB\"}}
```

how can I get value of ( product_brand )..I tried all other question answers but no luck.

when I try to get value it shows T_string or T_variable or 'subObject' errors.

```
$jsonStr = json_decode(str_replace('\"','"',$_POST['laptop']));
```

then what to do next...

I want to use value for SQL query in PHP.

There is no array in my JSON.

Thanks.

Comment: json_decode() didn't help?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php before `json_code()` or turn off `magic_quotes_gpc` in php.ini.

Comment: I used.. `$jsonStr = json_decode(str_replace('\"','"',$_POST['laptop']))` ... then what is next step..

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array when I use this code--> `echo $jsonStr->Laptop->product_brand;`

Comment: Got My Answer...
`$jsonStr = json_decode(str_replace('\"','"',$_POST['laptop'])); echo $jsonStr->Laptop->product_brand;`

Thanks..all

negative votes ban me from answering now... anyway thanks all and stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

JSON:

```
{\"Laptop\":{\"product_brand\":\"dd\",\"product_desc\":\"xx\"}
```

Get  *child json object* from *parent json object*...

```
$jsonStr = json_decode(str_replace('\"','"',$_POST['laptop']));
echo $jsonStr->Laptop->product_brand;
```

use '  ->  ' to drill down for Parsing JSON in PHP

if you want convert in array

```
$jsonStr = json_decode(str_replace('\"','"',$_POST['laptop']),true);
```

And Can use

```
print_r($jsonStr)
```

to get structure of JSON.

Thanks..all